# MATLAB: sample from population randomly many times?

Tags: matlab, functional-programming, statistics, probability

I am aware of MATLAB's `datasample` which allows to select `k` times from a certain `population`. Suppose `population=[1,2,3,4]` and I want to uniformly sample, with replacement, `k=5` times from it. Then:

```
datasample(population,k)
ans =
   1     3     2     4     1
```

Now, I want to repeat the above experiment `N=10000` times without using a for loop. I tried doing:

```
datasample(repmat(population,N,1),5,2)
```

But the output I get is (just a short excerpt below):

```
 1     3     2     1     3
 1     3     2     1     3
 1     3     2     1     3
 1     3     2     1     3
 1     3     2     1     3
 1     3     2     1     3
 1     3     2     1     3
 1     3     2     1     3
 1     3     2     1     3
```

Every row (result of an experiment) is the same! But obviously they should be different... It's as though some random seed is not updating between rows. How can I fix this? Or some other method I could use that avoids a for loop? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`datasample` interprets each column of your data as one element of your population, sampling among all columns.

To fix this you could call `datasample` N times in a loop, instead I would use `randi`

```
population(randi(numel(population),N,5))
```

assuming your population is always 1:p, you could simplify to:

```
randi(p,N,5)
```

Comment: You and rayryeng have the same solution. Thanks a lot, it works! Yours is a bit more concise, so I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @space_voyager - Cool.  Bear in mind that the code I wrote can generalize to any population vector you want.  The assumption with Daniel's code is that the population vector is always going to be `1:p` where `p` is the desired number of elements.  Either way, good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng: "assuming your population is always 1:p, you could simplify to" ;)

Comment: @Daniel bahaha :) yes I saw that comment.

Comment: It does not assume that I think, because randi returns the indices along population, which get converted back into specific population values when you do population(randi(...)).

Comment: @space_voyager - Yes, I glossed over the first part.  You are correct.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be confusing the way `datasample` works.  If you read the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/datasample.html) on the function, if you specify a matrix, it will generate a data sampling from a selection of rows in the matrix.  Therefore, if you simply repeat the `population` vector 10000 times, and when you specify the second parameter of the function - which in this case is how many rows of the matrix to extract, even though the actual row locations themselves are different, the actual rows over all of the matrix is going to be the same which is why you are getting that "error".

As such, I wouldn't use `datasample` here if it is your intention to avoid looping.  You can use `datasample`, but you'd have to loop over each call and you explicitly said that this is not what you want.

What I would recommend you do is first create your `population` vector to have whatever you desire in it, then generate a random index matrix where each value is between 1 up to as many elements as there are in `population`.  This matrix is in such a way where the number of columns is the number of samples and the number of rows is the number of trials.  Once you create this matrix, simply use this to index into your vector to achieve the desired sampling matrix.  To generate this random index matrix, [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) is a fine choice.

Something like this comes to mind:

```
N = 10000; %// Number of trials
M = 5; %// Number of samples per trial
population = 1:4; %// Population vector

%// Generate random indices
ind = randi(numel(population), N, M);

%// Get the stuff
out = population(ind);
```

Here's the first 10 rows of the output:

```
>> out(1:10,:)

ans =

     4     3     1     4     2
     4     4     1     3     4
     3     2     2     2     3
     1     4     2     2     2
     1     2     3     4     2
     2     2     3     2     1
     4     1     3     2     4
     1     4     1     3     1
     1     1     2     4     4
     1     2     4     2     1
```

I think the above does what you want.  Also keep in mind that the above code generalizes to any population vector you want.  You simply have to change the vector and it will work as advertised.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so both of the current answers both say don't use `datasample` and use `randi` instead. However, I have a solution for you with `datasample` and [`arrayfun`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html).

```
>> population = [1 2 3 4];
>> k = 5; % Number of samples
>> n = 1000; % Number of times to execute datasample(population, k)
>> s = arrayfun(@(k) datasample(population, k), n*ones(k, 1), 'UniformOutput', false);
>> s = cell2mat(s);
s =

     1     4     1     4     4
     4     1     2     2     4
     2     4     1     2     1
     1     4     3     3     1
     4     3     2     3     2
```

We need to make sure to use `'UniformOutput', false` with `arrayfun` as there is more than one output. The `cell2mat` call is needed as the result of `arrayfun` is a cell array.

Comment: This is how I did it before I got the above answers. I think the randi solution is cleaner, though! Thanks anyway.

Comment: that works!... though `arrayfun` is technically a loop.

Comment: @space_voyager Yes it is, I just wanted to do it with `datasample`.

Comment: Your solution is better in that datasample allows different probability distributions along the population! So I'd use your technique if that was my case.

Comment: @space_voyager Thanks.